# Node code keeps a sequence instead of asynchronous execution

Tags: node.js

Can anyone explain why this piece of code is executed in sequence with Node?

```
console.log('Main code, first line');
doThings(10000000, doThingsAfter);

function doThings(x,callback){
    console.log('Am in doThings(x,callback), value received is ' + x);
    for (var i= 0; i<x; i++){var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();} //wasting time here
    console.log('Time after '+ x +' times was ' + minutes);
    callback(minutes);
}

function doThingsAfter(minutes){
    console.log('I am at doThingsAfter(), so I am the callback and I received minute:' + minutes);
}
console.log('Main code, last line');
```

The result is:

- Main code, first line
- Am in doThings(x,callback), value received is 10000000
- Time after 10000000 times was 38
- I am at doThingsAfter(), so I am the callback and I received minute:38
- Main code, last line

Whereas I would expect

- Main code, first line
- Main code, last line
- Am in doThings(x,callback), value received is 10000000
- Time after 10000000 times was 38
- I am at doThingsAfter(), so I am the callback and I received minute:38

or at least

- Main code, first line
- Am in doThings(x,callback), value received is 10000000
- Main code, last line
- Time after 10000000 times was 38
- I am at doThingsAfter(), so I am the callback and I receives minutes:38

The thing is the last `console.log('Main code, last line');` shouldn't have to wait until the loop has finished. What am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: your code is completely sync, where would you expect it getting async? A loop is a synchronous operation, not a async one.

Comment: @JohannesMerz even if you get rid of the loop , the code still outputs the same thing

Comment: @0.sh it sure does. Said nothing else. I just guessed (based on his comment line) that thats the point where op expects to get things async and wanted to point out that it doesn't.

Comment: OK, let me put it this way: I need to do things that take time (`doThings`) and after it's done, do some other things (`doThingsAfter`) with the result of the first one **but** in the meantime, I want the main code to continue executing. @0.sh @JohannesMerz